# your screen size is bogus. Expect trouble

Tags: terminal

I opened terminal windows and I got a message

```
your screen size %d%d is bogus. Expect trouble
```

I closed the terminal and the next time I opened terminal, the message didn't show up.

What is this message and why did I receive it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This message comes from (perhaps other places) `procps`, which does a quick check to determine the screen width for `ps` command's notion of *width*.

`procps` makes this check in [`set_screen_size`](https://github.com/mmalecki/procps/blob/master/ps/global.c#L118), e.g., if the screen size is [too small](https://github.com/mmalecki/procps/blob/master/ps/global.c#L160) to print anything useful:

```
  if((screen_cols<9) || (screen_rows<2))
    fprintf(stderr,"Your %dx%d screen size is bogus. Expect trouble.\n",
      screen_cols, screen_rows
    );
```

You might see the *same* code (via cut/paste) in other programs, but this is the most likely one.

As to *why* the problem occurred: when starting a terminal emulator, it can be multiple processes which communicate, sharing the information about the pseudo-terminal connection.  Sometimes, the information is not shared rapidly enough, causing (usually) minor errors in the terminal settings.