# Tilda complains of bogus screen size at startup?

Tags: tilda

On Ubuntu 14.04, MATE desktop. I have just installed Tilda terminal, and so I added it to Startup Applications, just as `/usr/bin/tilda`. Rebooted, saw Tilda startup, and then noticed this:

[image: tilda]

"Your 131072x1 screen size is bogus. expect trouble"

Then I tried `killall tilda`, started tilda again, same message.

Anyone know how can I fix this bogus screen size issue?

Comment: I believe this message is thrown by `shopt -s checkwinsize` somewhere in your `.bashrc` or the system's `bashrc`. I think I also had this warning with `geany`. Not anymore.

Comment: Thanks @Nasha - `checkwinsize` seems like a useful option, so I wouldn't like to remove it; but maybe there\s a way to disable that check only for when Tilda is loaded...

Comment: Instead of taking the time to edit your prompt, you could have provided the message as text. Or even better: just google the error message and find the post Thomas' indicates **as the first result**

Comment: Sorry for that, I stopped reading when I saw the picture and realised you could have saved everyone’s trouble by using google.

Comment: @Anthon - I did provide the message as text; Ctrl-F it: "Your 131072x1 screen size is bogus. expect trouble"; also I find the answer of JdeBP here much more informing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### What is generating this message

This is not produced by the Bourne Again shell.  This is not produced by Tilda.

This is produced by the `ps` command from [the procps toolset](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps) performing [this check in its `set_screen_size()` function](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/7bf9457f71910b6fc57f8fb2223ff94a590db552/ps/global.c#L168).  The `ps` command demands that your terminal device be a minimum of 9 columns by 2 rows in order for it to be able to display things reasonably.  Somewhere, possibly unbeknownst to you, you are invoking `ps`.

The `ps` command obtains your terminal size directly from (the line discipline of) the terminal device attached to its standard I/O file descriptors, and allows that to be overridden by `COLUMNS` and `LINES` environment variables if their values are properly numeric.  You can see what your `ps` command is seeing in order to make its determination by running:

```
stty size ; printenv COLUMNS LINES
```

You can experiment with pulling `ps`'s leg by running things such as:

```
COLUMNS=65535 LINES=1 ps
```

If you have set the `COLUMNS` and `LINES` environment variables to the daft 131072×1 values, as shown by the output of `printenv`, then simply do not do that.  ☺  It is more probable however that the terminal device itself is reporting this size, which you will see from the output of `stty`.  (Note that all that the Bourne Again shell does with `checkwinsize` is set the values of these shell variables, which if not exported are not even passed to the `ps` command in its environment, to whatever the terminal device reports the size to be.  So `checkwinsize` is a red herring in that if the environment variables are nonsense, the terminal device *is itself reporting* nonsense, and the latter is the underlying problem to be addressed.)

Which is why whilst it isn't producing the message Tilda could be at fault.  The terminal device size is a shared resource that anything that has an open file descriptor to the terminal device can change arbitrarily with an `ioctl()` system call.  But it is *conventionally* set, in the scenario that one is using a software *terminal emulator program* like Tilda, by the terminal emulator program when the size of the GUI window in which the emulation is being displayed changes.  The terminal emulator program gets a GUI resize event, converts it into columns and lines, and sets the device size with `ioctl()`.

This is not to say that something else hasn't set the size to this nonsense.  After all, you can set it *yourself* to an arbitrary nonsense size by just running, for example, the command:

```
stty columns 1 rows 65535
```

Which brings us to …

### How to reset the terminal device size

If you find yourself in the position that the terminal device is reporting a nonsense size:

- If you are using a GUI terminal emulator, resize the GUI by a column/line or so.  This should trigger the `ioctl()` and set the terminal size to something reasonable.
- Set the size to something more reasonable with (for example):

  ```
  stty columns 80 rows 25
  ```
- Use the `reset` command.  Note that `reset` sets a lot of other stuff in addition to just the terminal device size.
- If your terminal emulator is DEC VT340/VT420 compatible, emit the appropriate DECSCPP amd DECSLPP/DECSNLS control sequences directly, or use [the nosh toolset](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/)'s [`console-resize`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/console-resize.html) (a.k.a. [`resizecons`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/resizecons.html)) command to emit them:

  ```
  resizecons 80x25
  ```

Comment: Thanks for that, @JdeBP - I will upvote this, once I have rep!

Comment: @JdeBP Please consider to delete your answer here and put it as an answer under [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259529/your-screen-size-is-bogus-expect-trouble), that way it much more likely to get attention and appreciation than hidden under this duplicate post that did not get closed quickly enough to block people from answering.

Comment: There's a Stack Exchange tool for moving answers intact, apparently.  You'll have to ask someone else to wield it, though.